# Unable to mount external NVME USB disk

Tags: usb, nvme

Hello I've a external NVME USB disk. It gets detected on windows (detect / create partitions / files / etc) and I can work with it.
However when I try plug it in my Ubuntu I get the following:

```
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1de1, idProduct=1101, bcdDevice=21.00
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: usb 1-2: Product: AM8180
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: AMicro
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 012345679193
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[679]: Error selecting on netlink socket: interrupted system call.
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 kernel: scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 mtp-probe[14694]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2"
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 mtp-probe[14694]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch_1-2...
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 mtp-probe[14711]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-2"
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 mtp-probe[14711]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 Thunar[14704]: thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb".
Apr 14 16:09:21 Quieter2 Thunar[14727]: thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb-storage".
Apr 14 16:09:22 Quieter2 usb_modeswitch[14734]: switch device 1de1:1101 on 001/006
Apr 14 16:09:42 Quieter2 systemd[1]: usb_modeswitch@1-2.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 14 16:09:42 Quieter2 systemd[1]: Finished USB_ModeSwitch_1-2.
```

I'm not sure why it is unsupported. There's not partitions on it.
I see it on lsusb (last one on the list):

```
deam0n@Quieter2:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0751 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1de1:1101 Actions Microelectronics Co. Generic Display Device (Mass storage mode)
```

Any ideas on how to install drivers or be able to create partitions on it?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: There are several questions about #not an MTP device# but unfortunately none have answers.

Comment: Is device NTFS formatted & then Windows has locked it by setting hibernation/fast start up flag? Linux NTFS driver will not default mount NTFS that is hibernated to prevent damage. Also many NVMe & SSD need firmware update. Not sure if you can do that when USB device.

Comment: There's no partitions on the drive. I've removed everything on Windows.